# MAX17260 after shutdown state

Tags: low-power, fuel-gauge

I am using the MAX17260 and during shpping set it to shutdown state
the battery is always connected to the MAX17260.
do we need to update the MAX17260 register after exiting from shut down mode?

Comment: Why can't you actually test the device to see if it's possible?

Comment: Have you read the sections about config registers in the datasheet?

Comment: I got the EVB and I will test it today